# Any idea what the red colour on the engine block in this photo is?

Tags: engine

Any ideas what the orange/rust color is in the photos below?

As well, what could be the source of it?

There is a lot of hard gunk buildup here.

Here is the image.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like Chevy Orange. What car/engine is it?

Comment: It is a Kia Pregio Van

Comment: Is it not just the remains of whatever paint was originally used on the block?

Comment: Did you notice any coolant leak?

Comment: Have not noticed any coolant leak. The rest of the block is not painted.

Comment: Could the hot oil have melted off some substance from that similarly colored orange mounting plate thing in the semi foreground right next to the the fuel injector? I'm assuming that thing is detachable since there's some kind of rivet that's visible to its top left corner.

Comment: I can only zoom in so much without loosing clarity.  Adding to that all the gunk makes hard to really see.   But it almost looks like a weld repair on the block at that location.   Maybe that is just the grease I am seeing.  A bit of cleaning and re-picture would help.   If it is welded then possible is some sort of block sealer.

Comment: I'll go buy some degreaser and clean up the area. What would a weld repair on that part of the block be for?

Comment: If by odd chance it is a weld repair, they are commonly done for various reasons depending on the engine.   Certain engine blocks have casting or design  flaws that can lead to small cracks in the block walls, some are repairs for over stress or over heating.  Some even relate to engine mount issues.

Comment: If it is a weld repair, can you comment on what significance that has for the longevity and reliability of the engine?

Comment: A good weld repair can make a block good as new.  I have engines that are 50-60 years old that some where in there life had a crack welded,  They still run strong.

Answer (score 4):

The color looks astonishing similar to [lead tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II,IV)_oxide). Decades ago used as a metal rustproofing and paint primer. Originally the golden gate bridge was rustproofed with that stuff. Now virtually everywhere prohibited because of his toxicity.

Are there any signs that this red colored stuff got painted on?
That being the case it could be possible that some previous owner (plumber, boiler mechanic) was trying to rust proof some weld repair and consequently endangering the next unfortunate guy who is working on the engine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what it is but I agree with @Pete that it does look a lot like grunged up Chevy Orange. The peculiar part is how it is spot painted. I'd like to upload an image that samples a couple of the orange areas and lay them side by side with other nearby patches. You can see how I blocked out a white background in the lower right corner and copied little patches of image to that region for side by side comparison. Hopefully the size and orientation of the rectangles are easy to spot in the parent image.

I'd say clean up the area and upload some additional images. It's an interesting mystery.

[image: sampling various patches]

Answer (score 0):

Your diesel engine has burnt some sort of substance on it from the radiator area rearward. The pinkish orange colour could indicate auto fluid mixed with coolant, this may indicate a cracked transmission oil cooler (within the radiator) mixing with coolant and blowing out from the radiator or overflow tank. Not sure without smelling or checking levels, also the  front base of the rocker cover has definitely seen heat also, you need to start troubleshooting by checking all fluid levels.

Cheers Hutch